# Storing MySQL connection details as a function in PHP (PDO)

Tags: php, mysql, function, pdo

I'm trying out the PDO extension, and was wondering if it were possible to store the opening of the DB connection as a function that could be called whenever needed. I tried some basic stuff, but it doesn't seem to work. Can it?

**Example Function**

```
function DB() {
$conn = new PDO('mysql:host='.DB_HOST.';dbname='.DB_NAME, DB_USER, DB_PASS);
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
if (!$conn) {
    echo "<br />MySQL SERVER CONNECTION ERROR.<br />\n";
}
if($conn) {
    return $conn;
}
}
```

**Example Useage**

```
function is_post_id($submitted) {

try {
    $id = $submitted;
    DB();   

    //check to see if there is a post
    //with an id matching the submitted query
    $qPOST= $conn->prepare('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM posts WHERE id = :id');
    $qPOST->execute(array('id' => $id)); 

    //results counted
    $cPOST= (int)$qPOST->fetchColumn();
    if($cPOST > 0) {
        return TRUE;
    }
    else {
        return FALSE;
    }
} catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

call it as :

$conn = $this->DB();

OR

$conn = $className->DB();

Comment: `$this` is not defined beforehand?

Comment: you would need to call $this if the function is within the same class. Otherwise if it is in another class, make an instance of that class and call in the second example.

Comment: Sorry, I'm missing something probably. There are no classes at all, just independent functions.